# Creating .net application that will run without user having to install dependencies

Tags: .net, deployment, .net-framework-version

I want to develop a wpf application that **runs on windows 8** without having the user install any dependencies. From doing research I found:

> Windows 8 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 4.5 as an OS
>   component, and it is installed by default.  It also includes the .NET
>   Framework 3.5 SP1 as an OS **component that is not installed by
>   default**.  The .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 can be added or removed via the
>   Programs and Features control panel.

I found that at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os.aspx

Anyhow if I build my wpf application using the .net framework 4.5 I believe it will run without the user having to install any dependencies (I am assuming user has windows 8). **But what if my application references an assembly that was created using the .net framework 2.0**. Once my wpf application make use of that assembly it will crash on the users computer?

If I want to prevent user from installing dependencies I will have to remove the assembly that was created using .net framework 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target of the executable is what matters here.  If you have an application that targets .NET 4, when it is run for the first time, the .NET 4 runtime will be loaded, and the entire application will run under the .NET 4 runtime, including any DLLs that were targeted at .NET 2.  The .NET 4 runtime can execute code that is targeted at older .NET versions.

So the user would not have to separately install .NET 2 to run an application that's targeted at .NET 4, even if it references .NET 2 DLLs.